# SQLite returning wrong integer value

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am getting strange wrong value from an INTEGER column in SQlite3. Here it is

From terminal I executed select satement

```html
sqlite> select userId, email, firstName, lastName, mobilePhone, passWord, signupDate, profilePicture from SCH_USERS where email = 'sujitdala@y.ccom';
8|sujitdala@y.ccom|Sujit|Dalai|**5106932562**|yas|2015-02-22 02:05:55 +0000|
```

The mobilePhone value is 5106932562
Now when I am executing same select statement in IOS I am getting different value
Here it is

```
NSString * sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select userId, email, firstName, lastName, mobilePhone, passWord, signupDate, profilePicture from SCH_USERS where email = '%@';", email];
NSLog(@"sql: %@", sql);
sqlite3_stmt * selectStatement;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite.database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &selectStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    while (sqlite3_step(selectStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        NSNumber *mobilePhone = [NSNumber numberWithInt:sqlite3_column_int(selectStatement, 4)];
        NSLog(@"mobile phone %@", mobilePhone);
    }
}
```

The result in log is 2015-02-21 18:05:55.171 Appointment Scheduler[40331:7035909] phone: 811965266

It's quite strange. Any help?

Comment: Use `sqlite3_column_int64`, or, better, `sqlite3_column_text`.

Answer (score 3):

Not that strange at all in fact … `5,106,932,562` minus `811,965,266` is `4,294,967,296`, and that just happens to be `2^32` – so you’re simply experiencing the effects of an *integer overflow* here.

And that’s were your mistake lies to begin with – storing phone numbers as integers, which they are of course not.

Store phone numbers as what they are – *strings*.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I did.